# Cleaner way to Pop item in list of list

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists:

```
a = [[1,2,'a','b'],[3,4,'c','d'],[5,6,'e','f']]
```

and I want the result:

```
[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
and
[['a','b'],['c','d'],['e','f']]
```

I can do it with a loop and pop but am wondering if there's a better way using slicing or a cleaner method:

```
d = []
for i in a:
    b = i.pop()
    c = i.pop()
    d.append([c,b])

In: a                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Out: [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]

In: d                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Out: [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']]
```

Comment: `b=[b[:2] for b in a];c=[c[2:] for c in a];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way other than iterating over the list of lists.

```
x,y = [i[:2] for i in a], [i[2:] for i in a]
print(x)
print(y)

[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']]
```

If you are open to using numpy then -

```
import numpy as np

x,y = np.array(a)[:,:2], np.array(a)[:,2:]
print(x)
print(y)
```

```
[['1' '2']
 ['3' '4']
 ['5' '6']]

[['a' 'b']
 ['c' 'd']
 ['e' 'f']]
```

Comment: Thank you for the two options. Either works for me but I think it would be faster for my code to not convert to numpy arrays

Comment: correct. but that depends on the size of the data and what you want to do afterwards as well :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it just with a list comprehension:

```py
a = [[1,2,'a','b'],[3,4,'c','d'],[5,6,'e','f']]

first_part = [x[:2] for x in a]
second_part = [x[2:] for x in a]
```

Comment: If would be nicer to change variable `x`  to  `sub`.  Readability still counts... 